# Having problems rendering data from react component - suggestions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm working on a simple react project, and am trying to create a table of products and their respective prices. Inside my `ProductRow` component, I'm using the `forEach()` method to loop through my product data and return the names of the products, which is then supposed to be rendered in the parent `ProductTable`  component - except it isn't. Any suggestions? Code as follows:

```
class FilterableProductTable extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <SearchBar/>
        <ProductTable products = {this.props.products}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class SearchBar extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Search'/>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

class ProductTable extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>price</th>
          </tr>
        <ProductRow products = {this.props.products}/>
         </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ProductRow extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const items = this.props.products
    return(
      <tr>
        {
          items.forEach(x=> {
           return <td>{x.name}</td>
          })
        }
      </tr>
    )
  }
}

const PRODUCTS = [
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
];
 
ReactDOM.render(
  <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach` - forEach returns nothing while `map` should return a jsx element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` instead of `forEach` .

For a detailed answer see the following articles:

> With .map() it creates a new array out of the results of the given function without harming the original array.

[Dev.to article](https://dev.to/torianne02/map-vs-foreach-pd4)

[Codeburst article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f#:%7E:text=map()%20allocates%20memory%20and,instead%20return%20a%20new%20array.)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Map` instead of `forEach` since it returns an array while `forEach` returns nothing.

- `forEach` is normally used when you're performing loops in an array, think of it as a substitute for `for` loops.
- `map` creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
class ProductRow extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const items = this.props.products
    return(
      <tr>
        {
          items.map(x=> {
           return <td>{x.name}</td>
          })
        }
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that! I got data rendering, but instead of each item being in its own row, all the items rendered as one big row, as follows: ```Football Baseball Basketball iPod Touch iPhone 5 Nexus 7 ``` Any ideas on how to get each item in it's own row? Cheers

Comment: use tr instead of td then for `x.name`